# Extracting a URL string with same results as a $_GET

Tags: php, string, get

Ok, so I have a string like so:

`index.php?page=test2;sa=blah`

And I need only to grab what gets returned using `$_GET['page']`, so it will return, `test2` in this case.  BUT page MUST be defined DIRECTLY after `index.php?` before it can return an actual string.  How do I do this?  I just need the same results returned from a $_GET for the page variable.  I can also have just this:

`index.php?page=blah`

Should return `blah`

or this:

`index.php?page=anything&sa=blah`

Returns `anything`

or this:

`index.php?action=blah;page=2`

Returns empty string, cause this is NOT directly after `index.php?`

or basically any url, but it needs to grab the variable of page if it exists, only after `index.php?`.  And sometimes page might not even exist at all, in this case, an empty string should be returned.

How can I do this?  I am not browsing to the URL in my browser, so, don't think $_GET will work, but it needs to simulate and return the EXACT same results that $_GET will return in the browser, but only if `page` is defined directly after `index.php?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use following code:

```
function get($name, $url) {
   $src = parse_url($url);
   $src = $src['query'];
   parse_str($src, $tag);
   return $tag[$name];
}
```

Comment: Your example isn't helping cause it is returning the entire text after `index.php?`.  So doing the same thing with your example returns the following:  `test2;sa=blah`  It should just return `test2` only.  How to do this??

Comment: @SoLo Which is the correct behavior, since `;` is not a delimiter. `&` is.

Comment: either one works on my site, so how to mimic the `$_GET['page']` here??  In any case, even if I use & as a delimiter, with this answer, it still returns:  `test2&sa=blah`

Comment: Ok, I got this working using your approach to this.  Thank You for the example :)

Answer (score 3):

[`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) are your friends.

Comment: Specifically, `parse_str`.  And use the second (array output) parameter, rather than relying on injection into the current scope (which could be global).

Comment: Those functions will get you in the right directions, I've done this as a method to turn a url into an array and vice versa and it becomes trivial with these functions.

Comment: hey I tried, this on the following and doesn't work:  `$link = 'index.php?page=test2;sa=blah'; parse_str($link, $page_output); $page_output['page'] returns empty string`

Comment: So, how come `$page_output['page']` is not working??

Comment: @SoLo First parse the URL with `parse_url`. `parse_str` only parses the *query* part (the part after `?`).

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the element received at $_GET is equal that you expect by comparison or a simple if statement. if not, then process the string to find it (if needed). Maybe also used the index of the elemnt to determine if process or not.